# Delegate seems to be set to nil automatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, macos

I am making a helper class. This helper class consists of a NSObject class which I would interact with and a UIViewController that does some other stuff.

Here is what happens, in my app delegate or wherever I allocate my NSObject class:

```
MyObjectClass *class = [[MyObjectClass alloc] init];
[class setDelegate:self];
```

Now, this delegate is something I created like this:

```
@protocol MyDelegate
-(void) someCall;
@end
@interface MyHelperClass : NSObject {
    id <MyDelegate> delegate;


}
@property (retain, nonatomic) id <MyDelegate> delegate;
```

So this works great. But here's the problem. If I allocate my helper class and set it's delegate to a view controller or something and then call one of my methods that open my helper view controller the delegate stops working. After debugging it seems it has some memory address until I pop up the other view controller and when I return to it, the memory address of the delegate is 0x0.

My questions is how could this happen? Do I need to do something special with my delegate to stop it from releasing? (I don't release it anywhere myself) Do I need to retain it? **How do I keep it allocated even when I open my viewcontroller so I can continue using it?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you do this... ... "If I allocate my helper class and set it's delegate to a view controller or something and then call one of my methods that open my helper view controller the delegate stops working"....please post your code ..... I think this is problem of reference loss.code will help.

Comment: Ravin,I've showed the code on how I allocate my NSObject class above. I call a method from for my delegate like this:     [delegate someCall];

Comment: MyObjectClass *class = [[MyObjectClass alloc] init];
[class setDelegate:self];
are you writing someCall method in your self? have you tried with someother name than the  class, for MyObjectClass?

Comment: "pop to the other view controller [...] return to it". That part is not very clear and you should post the code that does this. My guess is you're ending up with a different instance of MyHelperClass, not the instance on which you had set the delegate. If you post more code, someone can figure that out.

Comment: i switch to a login view controller:     [view presentModalViewController:loginView animated:YES];

Comment: then i just allocate another instance of my class to call it's method

Comment: Also, delegate ivars are usually assigned instead of retained.

Answer (score 0):

the memory address of the delegate is 0x0 means that it was never assigned, not that it was released. if it was released it wouldn't be a valid address anymore, but it would be the same address that it was before it was released.